# Parameters to method of type "Binding" in Spring AMQP RabbitMQ with SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I am trying to understand this code which is RabbitMQ configuration.

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitMqConfig {// rabbitmq配置类

public static final String EXCHANGE = "com.mldn.fish.exchange";// 配置交换空间

public static final String ROUTINGKEY = "com.mldn.fish.routingkey";// 创建一个路由

public static final String QUEUE_NAME = "com.mldn.fish.queue";// 创建队列名字

@Bean
public DirectExchange getDirectExchange() {
    return new DirectExchange(RabbitMqConfig.EXCHANGE);// 得到交换空间
}

@Bean
public Queue getQueue() {
    return new Queue(RabbitMqConfig.QUEUE_NAME);// 得到队列名字
}

@Bean
public Binding bindingExchangeQueue(DirectExchange exchange, Queue queue) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(RabbitMqConfig.ROUTINGKEY);// 绑定交换空间和队列
}
}
```

Here,what do the parameters of the method "bindingExchangeQueue" mean?
Should it be -

```
@Bean
public Binding bindingExchangeQueue(DirectExchange getDirectExchange, Queue getQueue) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(getQueue).to(getDirectExchange).with(RabbitMqConfig.ROUTINGKEY);// 绑定交换空间和队列
}
```

Basically I want to know what these parameters carry and should the name match with method name configured as @Beans. Can anyone explain this please?

I also found a sample where multiple queues are configured.
Please find below -

```
@Bean
Queue queueFoo() {
    return new Queue("queue.foo", false);
}

@Bean
Queue queueBar() {
    return new Queue("queue.bar", false);
}

@Bean
TopicExchange exchange() {
    return new TopicExchange("exchange");
}

@Bean
Binding bindingExchangeFoo(Queue queueFoo, TopicExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queueFoo).to(exchange).with("queue.foo");
}

@Bean
Binding bindingExchangeBar(Queue queueBar, TopicExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queueBar).to(exchange).with("queue.bar");
}
```

Here, the bean bindingExchangeFoo has the Queue parameter name as queueFoo, which matches with the @Bean queueFoo. Otherwise, since there are now 2 queues, how would it know which queue to bind based only on return type?

Comment: @Gary Russell Sir, Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to start from the Spring Framework Dependency Injection: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-bean-annotation

The parameter name of that `@Bean` method doesn't bring any value. The type is very important and a bean with such a type is going to be injected here or you'll if fail if there are more than one or you don't have one with a `@Primary`.

If you definitely want to inject a paerticular bean by its name you should consider to add to such an argument a `@Qualifier` annotation: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers

Comment: Thank You. I will go through the documentation, I am new to Spring. How should it be configured if there are multiple queues? If there are multiple queue configurations, then does the parameter name have to be matched with the @Bean method name which configures the queue?

Comment: Well, I said you: you need to use a `@Qualifier` in that case. The parameter name is erased after compilation.

Comment: I have edited the question with a sample code snippet having 2 queue configurations.Is the binding correct there?

Comment: No that's not. You have to add `@Qualifier` for each `Queue` argument.